# Writing a "Bean Counter" for Eloquent JavaScript Task

Tags: javascript

In this task from *Eloquent JavaScript*, you are asked to write two functions. One to count the number of ""'s in a string input. The next function must take two inputs; one string to search and one string to identify the target character to search for.

I have errors in both. In the first function, my `count` is always returned as `1`. In the second one, it simply returns `undefined`.

Can someone help me find my mistake?

```
function countBs(str) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) === "B") {
            count++;
        }
        return (count);
    }
}

console.log(countBs("BBBBBBBBC"));

function countChar(str, char) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) === "char") {
            count++;
            return (count);
        }
    }
}

console.log(countChar("kakkerlak", "k"));
```

Comment: I am trying to learn to code so I did the CodeCademy courses and some other online courses. One suggested resource was the Eloquent JavaScript book so I am working through that now.

Comment: @Utkanos why is the fact that it is study (or homework) relevant?

Comment: This line perhaps: `str.charAt(i) === "char"`?  This line is saying that `str.charAt(i)` should be equal to the *string value* `"char"`.  You might want the parameter `char`.

Comment: @DavinTryon I wondered the same. I was rebuked for asking on CodeReview and they said this was indeed the place for this sort of question. If its not, then apologies. I am just passionately trying to learn a new skill independently and thought this was the purpose of this resource.

Comment: @DavinTryon what is wrong with that line? On jsFiddle it idicates some sort of error on the "function countChar(str, char) {"  line.

Comment: I think you want `char`, not `"char"`.  You want to reference the parameter, correct?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you are returning the count within the for loop, so it returns after it searches the first character.  In the second function you are also using the string "char" instead of the variable char for comparing.

If you want to do it your way, here's the correct code:

```js
function countBs(str) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) === "B") {
            count++;

        }
    }
        return (count); // return outside of for loop
}



console.log(countBs("BBBBBBBBC"));


function countChar(str, char) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) === char) { // use the variable char instead of  the string "char"
            count++;
        }
    }
            return (count); // return outside of the for loop
}
console.log(countChar("kakkerlak", "k"));
```

Here's another way to do what you want. (using [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions))

```js
function countBs(str) {
    var length1 = str.length;
    var length2 = str.replace(/B/g,"").length;
    return length1 - length2;
}



console.log(countBs("BBBBBBBBC"));


function countChar(str, char) {
    var length1 = str.length;
    var regexp =  new RegExp(char, "g");
    var length2 = str.replace(regexp,"").length;
    
    return length1 - length2;
}
console.log(countChar("kakkerlak", "k"));
```

Comment: As op is trying to learn, it may be helpful to also include the solution using the methods he's trying to employ.

Comment: Yep, just added that!

Comment: Thank you @JohnHarding. I moved my "return()" value outside one set of curly brackets with that problem in mind and now see I was still short! Thank you so much. The second error I couldn't identify for the life of me. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Austin, don't forget to choose an answer when your problem has been solved! If it hasn't been solved, please update your question!

Answer (score 4):

You've got two small errors that require the following changes:

- don't quote your `char` variable in the `if` statement
- `return` after the loop is complete, not after the first match

Full code for `countChar()`:

```js
function countChar(str, char) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) === char) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return (count);
}

//test
alert(countChar("kakkerlak", "k"));
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer

```
function countBs(Str) 
{
  let char = "B" ;
  return  String(Str).split(char).length - 1; 

 } 
function countChar(Str, char) 
{
  return  String(Str).split(char).length - 1; 

 }
```

Comment: I like the split for performance reasons; But, given that this is homework and dealing with strings I think the homework is a practice for using str[i] or str.charAt(i).

Comment: Number of operations is generally an advanced course.

Answer (score 0):

```
function  countBs(stringVal,charVal){
    var count = 0;
    for(var i=0 ; i<stringVal.length ; i++)
    {
        if(stringVal.charCodeAt(i) === charVal.charCodeAt(0))
            count++;
    }

  return count;
}

//console.log(countBs("abcDBAB"));

function countChar(stringVal, charTobeCount){
  var newCount = countBs(stringVal, charTobeCount);
  return newCount;
}

console.log(countChar("abcDBAB", 'B'));
```

Comment: Give enough explanation also. Otherwise it won't be useful for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Bam... Short, sweet and clean.

```
function countChar(string, character){
    var count = 0;
    for(var x = 0; x < string.length; x++){
        if(string[x] == character) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first version, your return statement is inside the inner for loop.  Simply move it outside:

```
function countBs(str){
    let count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if (str[i] == "B") {count++;}
    }
return count;
}
```

Then you can easily add a second parameter by updating the code as follows:

```
function countChar(str, character){
    let count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if (str[i] == character) {count++;}
    }
return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, write the countBs function.
Let's create it

```
function countBs(str) {
    let count = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] === "B") {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
console.log(countBs("BeBeBBbhBcBBBBbbbb"));
```

Output

```
9
```

Now using the countChar function

```
let countBs = function(str) {
    return countChar(str, "e");
}

function countChar(str, char) {
    let count = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] === char) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
console.log(countBs("BeBeBBbhBcBeBBBbbbbebe"));
```

Output

```
5
```